# Можно ли заполнить массив не нулями по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

Как я понял, по стандарту заполняется только первый элемент массива, а остальные должны заполняться нулями.

```
int ar[10] = {-1};
int ar2[10][10] = {-1,};
```

Можно ли как-то задать значение по умолчанию не равное нулю всем элементам массива в момент объявления? Может, что-то есть в новом стандарте? Или только циклом?

Comment: Интересно. Но в VS не работает. Вот именно такое и ожидал найти. Значит, по идее, ничего нового не добавлено в стандарт.

Comment: @manking, ну, не знаю, как в общем случае, а для `int a[]` (думаю, в винде для short) можно выкрутиться и в крестах

    int a[5] = {(wmemset((wchar_t *)a, 1, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])), 1)};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cout << a[i];  // да, выводит 5 единичек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Си (по крайней мере gcc (This is a GNU extension)) можно

```
int a[] = { [0 ... 19] = 1}
```

и т.п. (см. например, [5.20 Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)),
а в С++ похоже нет.

Comment: С этими расширениями можно и [в плюсах](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HSOG1aDevpf8y7Bb).

Answer (score 3):

В C++ вы пользуетесь не нативными массивами, а STL-контейнерами.

Для них такая инициализация доступна:

```
vector<int> vec(5, 42);
```

инициализирует вектор пятью значениями 42: http://ideone.com/nOTYv9

---

В дополнение к отличному ответу [[@jfs](/users/23044/jfs)](/users/23044/jfs), если скоростная инициализация важна, вы можете воспользоваться и обычным метапрограммированием:

1) пишем утилиту-генератор (`generate.cpp`)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, int* argv[])
{
    auto val = argv[1];
    auto count = atoi(argv[2]);
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        cout << val << "," << endl;
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

2) Используем её в проекте:

```
generate 42 5 >arrinit.h
```

3) Ссылаемся в коде:

```
    int[] arr =
    {
#include "arrinit.h"
    };
```

Comment: Нет, нужно именно для нативных массивов, в си++ компиляторах(VS).

Comment: @manking: В одну строчку нельзя. Просто используйте [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

    int arr[5];
    std::fill_n(arr, _countof(arr), 42);

Макрос `_countof` специфичен для visual studio, он возвращает размер массива. Без него можно написать просто `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`, но макрос на самом деле [хитрее](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3368883/276994) и использует шаблоны.

Comment: @VladD, это же ведь можно вставить и в инициализацию массива (вместо wmemset() у меня).

Comment: @avp: Да, но в Visual Studio нет gcc extensions, так что `{}`-выражение не скомпилируется.

Comment: Пусть бросает винду. Все равно, похоже, что скоро у нас она станет неактуальна.

Comment: @avp: Ну, заказ и работа есть, наверное, здесь и сейчас, так что осваивать линукс всё равно придётся в свободное от работы время.

---
Да и C++, наверное, не лучший выбор.

Comment: А с другой стороны, и  в винде можно g++ использовать (хотя, если на работе есть правило писать для VS ...).

Ладно, пусть сам думает.

Comment: "std::fill_n(arr, _countof(arr), 42);"
Да мне проще циклом пройтись, так наглядней будет. 
Не, с винды нельзя сходить, MFC много.
Сомневаюсь, что windows под санкции попадёт, у него аналогов для ПК нет в мире, а разработать что то подобное у нас не смогут и за 15 лет.

Comment: @manking: Это да, циклом нагляднее. С другой стороны, если вы упрячете заполнение в функцию, её код будет ничем не отличаться от `std::fill_n`.

Если вы на MFC, тут с платформы не уйдёшь.

---
Вместо `std::fill_n` можно использовать [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

    std::fill(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 42);

Comment: @manking, ну кто бы мог представить, что пармезан с хамоном попадут под *наши* санкции?

А вот в случае с M$ они были бы намного логичнее (тем более, что 95% пользователей Word используют не более 5% функций этой программы).

Comment: @manking: Не нужно свой цикл писать, в котором можно баги завести, когда есть стандартный алгоритм, который все знают и делает тоже самое эффективно. Это мне напомнило: Sean Parent (Adobe, Photoshop) высказал радикальную цель "no raw loop". Рекомендую посмотреть презентацию (достаточно на код до и после посмотреть) [C++ Seasoning (2013)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning).

Comment: @jfs: Программист, который сделает ошибку в таком цикле, профессионально непригоден, так что это не имеет права быть серьёзным аргументом. Писать цикл или воспользоваться библиотечной функцией — вопрос читаемости кода и лёгкости его модификации, то есть по существу coding standards, принятых в конкретной команде разработчиков.

Comment: @VladD: чушь. Ошибаются все. У нас непогрешимых нет. Человек с опытом никогда не скажет, что он пишет код без ошибок, каким бы простым этот код не казался на первый взгляд.

Comment: @jfs: Ошибаются все — это да, но ошибиться можно и в вызове библиотечной функции, так что снова не аргумент. Говорить вслух «я не буду писать тривиальный цикл, вызову библиотечную функцию» — _особенно_ если такие функции в команде не являются идиоматическими — позёрство и самолюбование, опасное для разработки.

Код `std::fill_n(arr, _countof(arr), 42);` для меня лично мене читабелен, чем прямой цикл. Но ориентироваться надо не на личные вкусы, а на стандарт, принятый в команде.

Comment: @VladD: Если цикл действительно тривиален, например, `for (auto& e : arr) e = 42;` то он даже выигрывает по отсутствию лишних движущихся частей по сравнению с `fill(begin(a), end(a), 42);` (но обычно наоборот). Я посмотрел, `clang` генерирует в обоих случая идентичный код.

Не нужно свысока на простые циклы смотреть, например, `for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)` может быть неверен, если `int` 32битный, а нужно адресовать большее пространство (4G+). Я утверждаю, что подобные ошибки возможны (я не понял при чём здесь самолюбование).

Comment: @jfs: Самолюбованием было бы писать код, непонятный команде, но более «крутой», т. к. это радует лишь эго программиста, но не способствует хорошему общекомандному результату.

(С циклом по `int`-счётчику вы хорошо подметили, но, надеюсь, компилятор это заметит и выдаст warning насчёт сравнения signed и unsigned.)

Comment: @VladD: Не нужно передёргивать. В какой команде вызов `fill()` является проявлением "крутизны". Я предположу, что это искренняя ошибка, а не желание оскорбить с вашей стороны.

Вот явный список почему лучше использовать стандартный алгоритм (я кратко упомянул их в самом первом комментарии и в указанном видео более подробно о преимуществах говорится): 

- узнаваемость (сразу ясно, что код делает)
- меньше кода - меньше ошибок
- эффективность (как правило существует несколько реализаций, например, для RandomAccessIterator, ForwardIterator)
- .. другие причины, почему велосипед не надо изобретат

Comment: @jfs: У меня и в мыслях не было оскорбить вас каким бы то ни было образом, прошу прощения, если моё замечание навело на такие мысли.

Я видел команды, в которых `fill` таки является неуместным «проявлением крутизны». Особенно в разработке на embedded-платформах, где отход от чистого C до сих пор считается опасным, и где до сих пор компилятор выдаёт код хуже, чем соптимизированный вручную.

Да и мне лично прямая инициализация кажется более читаемой, чем прямой цикл.

Comment: @jfs: По пунктам:

* Узнаваемость субъективна, зависит от команды. Если использование стандартных контейнеров в некоторой команде (как например у ТС, судя по всему) не является самочевидной идиомой, то уж весь `<algorithm>` тем более.
* Насчёт количества кода, вы ведь сами построили пример с очень коротким `for`.

Comment: @jfs:

* Говорить об эффективности имеет смысл лишь для достаточно «общего» кода, в котором цикл может быть менее эффективным. В конкретно нашем случае эффективнее цикла может быть лишь `memset` (который более в духе ручной оптимизации — превращает ли clang инициализацию в memset?) и вынесение инициализации в момент компиляции (то есть, расположение преинициализированных данных в сегменте данных) — это, думаю, оптимизация, которую современные компиляторы пока не делают (хотя был бы приятно удивлён, если бы делали).

Answer (score 2):

@VladD показал две хорошие опции:

- использовать C++ контейнеры, такие как `vector`, которые поддерживают подобную инициализацию
- вызвать `std::fill_n()`/`std::fill()` -- если необходим именно обычный массив, то это предпочтительный вариант.

Пока измерения производительности не покажут, что инициализация массива является узким местом в программе, можно [другие опции](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065774/4279) не рассматривать.

В качестве неразумной опции, можно произвести [инициализацию массива во время компиляции с помощью шаблонов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2978259/4279):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  template<int... args> struct ArrayHolder {
    static const int data[sizeof...(args)];
  };

  template<int... args>
  const int ArrayHolder<args...>::data[sizeof...(args)] = { args... };

  template<size_t N, int value, int... args>
  struct generate_array {
    typedef typename generate_array<N-1, value, value, args...>::result result;
  };

  template<int value, int... args>
  struct generate_array<0, value, args...> {
    typedef ArrayHolder<args...> result;
  };
}

int main() {
  typedef generate_array<5, 42>::result A;
  for (auto x : A::data) std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 initialize-array.cc && ./a.out
42
42
42
42
42
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main(){
        int arr1[] = { 1, 2, 5 }; // массив из целых чисел 1 2 5
        int arr11[3] = { 1, 2, 5 }; // то же что и выше

        int arr2[3][3] = { 1, 2, 3, // двумерный массив 
                           4, 5, 6, // заполненный целыми
                           7, 8, 9  // числами от 1 до 9
                          };

        return 0;
    }
```

UPD: ещо нашел вариант инициализации массива

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    valarray<int> v(5);

    v = 12; // присвоить всем значениям массива число 12

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << v[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: за что минус?

Comment: @perfect то, что вы предлагаете, называется китайским кодом - забивать все значения вручную. Это еще может быть сносно для массива размером в 5-10 элементов. А если этих элементов будет тысяча? Тогда уж, ей-богу, лучше воспользоваться циклом.

Comment: @DreamChild я, конечно, не жалуюсь, но зачем нужен огромный массив из одних единиц? Странно, но, по-вашему, в стандарте языка указан именно китайский код.

Comment: @perfect, по моему должно быть просто очевидно, что автора вопроса интересовал вовсе не тривиальный вариант, предложенный Вами  
(в случае же сомнений лучше уточнить, что на самом деле нужно автору, сделав  комментарий к вопросу, а не писать ответ сразу).

Comment: @avp каков вопрос, таков ответ. Я так понимаю, вопросами пользуется не только автор, но и приходящие люди, в этом и смысл вопросников. А вот принятый ответ @manking вообще в С++ не работает, хотя метка-тег стоит именно С++.

Comment: @perfect, так в этом ответе явно же написано -- в Си (gcc) можно, а в С++ нет (такой очевидный способ инициализации там не предусмотрен)  
(замаскированный намек на то, что лучше вообще отказаться от С++, на самом деле причин больше и они упрятаны значительно глубже, если интересно, то [начните с размышления над этим](https://toster.ru/q/27307) (и не забудьте прочесть материал по ссылкам оттуда)).

Comment: @perfect
Я задавал вопрос, чтобы узнать, есть ли что-то подобное, что написал @avp, в стандарте С++ или в новых или планируемых стандартах языка.
Как раз именно это, языковую конструкцию для заполнения массива данными по умолчанию, без какой-либо дополнительной обработки.

Comment: обновил ответ. нашел еще один способ инициализировать массив значений числом в любой момент

Comment: @perfect: О, круто, не слыхал раньше о `valarray`.